# JavaScript: filter() for Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, filtering

ECMAScript 5 has the `filter()` prototype for `Array` types, but not `Object` types, if I understand correctly.

How would I implement a `filter()` for `Object`s in JavaScript?

Let's say I have this object:

```
var foo = {
    bar: "Yes"
};
```

And I want to write a `filter()` that works on `Object`s:

```
Object.prototype.filter = function(predicate) {
    var result = {};

    for (key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && !predicate(this[key])) {
            result[key] = this[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

This works when I use it in the following demo, but when I add it to my site that uses jQuery 1.5 and jQuery UI 1.8.9, I get JavaScript errors in FireBug.

```js
Object.prototype.filter = function(predicate) {
  var result = {};
  for (key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && !predicate(this[key])) {
      console.log("copying");
      result[key] = this[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
};

var foo = {
  bar: "Yes",
  moo: undefined
};

foo = foo.filter(function(property) {
  return typeof property === "undefined";
});

document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(foo, undefined, '  ');
console.log(foo);
```

```css
#disp {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace
}
```

```html
<div id="disp"></div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get, specifically?

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? Post them if possible :)

Comment: There's a bit of ambiguous history wrt jQuery and scripts that extend `Object.prototype`: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2721

Comment: exactly what I needed, except that you must remove the "!" in the !predicate(this[key]) to have the real filter method.

Comment: Those even mentioning extending the Object prototype, who are not interns,  get my recommendation to get immediately fired.  There is NO USE CASE where that is a desirable solution. You are basically rewriteing the language with that, since you took the one thing everything in JS is and said: let me make that a little bit different. Yes the language lets you mess with its highest prototype but you should really know better. To make you an analogy - imagine if you took your car and made it a little bit different. Breaks are no longer working if speed is between 59 and 60.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Never ever extend `Object.prototype`.

Horrible things will happen to your code. Things will break. You're extending *all* object types, including object literals.

Here's a quick example you can try:

```
    // Extend Object.prototype
Object.prototype.extended = "I'm everywhere!";

    // See the result
alert( {}.extended );          // "I'm everywhere!"
alert( [].extended );          // "I'm everywhere!"
alert( new Date().extended );  // "I'm everywhere!"
alert( 3..extended );          // "I'm everywhere!"
alert( true.extended );        // "I'm everywhere!"
alert( "here?".extended );     // "I'm everywhere!"
```

---

Instead create a function that you pass the object.

```
Object.filter = function( obj, predicate) {
    let result = {}, key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !predicate(obj[key])) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: @patrick: you might wish to give a reason, so it is slightly more informative :P

Comment: @Martin: I'm hoping to appeal to OP's fear of the unknown. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: give a man a bread and you'll feed him for a day, teach him how to bake and you'll feed him for a lifetime  (or something, I'm danish, I don't know the correct English sayings ;)

Comment: @Dykam: Yeah, I originally saw the question as *why is this breaking my code*. Updated with a solution.

Comment: @Martin: Make him afraid of heights, and he'll never die in a plane crash. ;o)

Comment: @patrick, don't forget to declare the `key` variable in the `for-in` loop ;)

Comment: @CMS: Ugh, you caught me on that again! I'm not sure how many more times I'll be able to use the copy/paste defense. :o) EDIT: Fixed. And thanks. :o)

Comment: You're doing it wrong...

    !predicate(obj[key])

should be

    predicate(obj[key])

Comment: @pyrotechnick: No. First, the main point of the answer is to not extend `Object.prototype`, but rather to just place the function on `Object`. Second, *this is the OP's code*. Clearly OP's intention is to have `.filter()` be such that it *filters out* the positive results. In other words, it is a negative filter, where a positive return value means it is *excluded* from the result. If you look at the jsFiddle example, he's filtering out existing properties that are `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick dw: No. First, I didn't mention extending/not extending prototypes. Second, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter -- "Creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function." Implementing the exact opposite on a global seems pretty silly, doesn't it?

Comment: @pyrotechnick: That's right, you didn't mention extending/not extending prototypes, and that's my point. You said I'm doing it wrong, but the only "it" I'm doing is telling OP to not extend `Object.prototype`. From the question: **"This works..., but when I add it to my site..., I get JavaScript errors"** If OP decides to implement a `.filter()` with the opposite behavior of that of `Array.prototpe.filter`, that's up to him/her. Please leave a comment under the question if you want to notify OP that the code is wrong, but don't tell me that *I'm* doing it wrong when it isn't my code.

Comment: What's the point of having to call this with Object.filter(...)?  Is that some kind of coding convention?  It doesn't need to be a function on Object.

Comment: Can someone please explain the pattern 
```for (key in obj){if obj.hasOwnProperty(key){....}}```
AFAIK, every key in this for loop is an enumerable property of obj, and hence obj.hasOwnProperty will always return true. What am I missing? In which cases will it return false?

Comment: @BenCarp objects come with other properties not defined by the user, built-in ones so its just to avoid those

Comment: @MartinJespersen i don't think the saying needs further translation, it is very accurate the way it is.

Comment: @MartinJespersen It's "give a man a fish; feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish; feed him for a lifetime". My favorite variation: "Give a man a fire; he'll be warm for a day; Set a man on fire; he'll be warm for the rest of his lifetime"

Comment: +1 for answering the question while also explaining why not to.   Someone *might* want to extend objects (a test suite that checks for people doing bad things?), which I did.   So many SO answers tell you not to do something while forgetting to tell you how to do it.

Comment: @user113716, I believe pyrotechnick is right, in a sense. Sure, you answered OP's question, but as it turns out, this is the top answer to a SO question with 424k views. The fact is, most people are going to come here looking for a Object.filter function, not what you have written. I came back to write this comment because the filter function I copied from your answer wasn't working and I imagine that isn't the first time that has happened. Regardless, thank you for writing such a well thought out response to OPs question.

Answer (score 464):

First of all, [it's considered bad practice to extend `Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes). Instead, provide your feature as stand-alone function, or if you really want to extend a global, provide it as utility function on `Object`, just like there already are `Object.keys`, `Object.assign`, `Object.is`, ...etc.

I provide here several solutions:

1. Using `reduce` and `Object.keys`
2. As (1), in combination with `Object.assign`
3. Using `map` and spread syntax instead of `reduce`
4. Using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`

#### 1. Using `reduce` and `Object.keys`

With [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to implement the desired filter (using ES6 [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```js
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

// Example use:
var scores = {
    John: 2, Sarah: 3, Janet: 1
};
var filtered = Object.filter(scores, score => score > 1); 
console.log(filtered);
```

Note that in the above code `predicate` must be an *inclusion* condition (contrary to the *exclusion* condition the OP used), so that it is in line with how [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works.

#### 2. As (1), in combination with `Object.assign`

In the above solution the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is used in the `reduce` part to return the mutated `res` object. This could of course be written as two statements instead of one expression, but the latter is more concise. To do it without the comma operator, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead, which *does* return the mutated object:

```js
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => Object.assign(res, { [key]: obj[key] }), {} );

// Example use:
var scores = {
    John: 2, Sarah: 3, Janet: 1
};
var filtered = Object.filter(scores, score => score > 1); 
console.log(filtered);
```

#### 3. Using `map` and spread syntax instead of `reduce`

Here we move the `Object.assign` call out of the loop, so it is only made once, and pass it the individual keys as separate arguments (using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)):

```js
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.assign(...Object.keys(obj)
                    .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
                    .map( key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }) ) );

// Example use:
var scores = {
    John: 2, Sarah: 3, Janet: 1
};
var filtered = Object.filter(scores, score => score > 1); 
console.log(filtered);
```

#### 4. Using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`

As the solution translates the object to an intermediate array and then converts that back to a plain object, it would be useful to make use of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (ES2017) and the opposite (i.e. [create an object from an array of key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682482/5459839)) with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (ES2019).

It leads to this "one-liner" method on `Object`:

```js
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
                  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(predicate));

// Example use:
var scores = {
    John: 2, Sarah: 3, Janet: 1
};

var filtered = Object.filter(scores, ([name, score]) => score > 1); 
console.log(filtered);
```

The predicate function gets a key/value pair as argument here, which is a bit different, but allows for more possibilities in the predicate function's logic.

Comment: Could it be more complex query? For example: `x => x.Expression.Filters.Filter`

Comment: @IamStalker, did you try? It does not matter, as long as you provide a valid function in the second argument. NB: I have no idea what `.Filter` is at the end, but if it is a function, you need to call it ( `x => x.Expression.Filters.Filter()` )

Comment: so long! can be done on 1 line . [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40562289/747579)

Comment: Newer features may make for less code, but they also make for [*slower performance*](https://jsperf.com/ed-3-vs-es-2015-vs-es-2016/1). Ed 3 compliant code runs more than twice as fast in most browsers.

Comment: TypeScript version of the last variant: https://gist.github.com/OliverJAsh/acafba4f099f6e677dbb0a38c60dc33d

Comment: To more closely mimic the Array.filter method, I would suggest using the following arguments when calling the predicate
(value, propertyName, object)

`predicate(obj[key], key, obj)`

Comment: This can be a question in itself.  Which of these should I use to get a value in an object :)

Comment: @Fabricio, to get a "value in an object", you just do `object[key] = value`. Yes, if you are stuck on a coding problem, then please ask a new question. If you want to have info about efficiency, good coding style, for *working* code, then check out [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have no doubts this is the best solution of all. Congratulations. My favorite solution is the combination with `entries` and `fromEntries`. So simple, yet so readable, comprehensible, powerful and a higher-level abstraction!

Comment: Solution 3 fails for me if there are null values in the object, not exactly sure how I should deal with that

Comment: @CiaranGallagher, when I add `other: null` as extra property in the sample object, then snippet #3 still runs fine. I suppose your filter condition is checking a property of each value, which only makes sense if your values are not `null`. You can use the `??` operator in your filter condition if that is your case. But this has little to do with the answer here, but more with providing a solid filter condition.

Comment: How would one put solution #1 into a utility file and export/import it?

Comment: @lowcrawler, there is nothing to export, as this mutates the global `Object` variable. There is no `export` needed, and you can just do `import 'myfile'` without assignment.

Comment: As @RobG hinted: how would these different approaches compare performance-wise?

Answer (score 164):

### Solution in Vanilla JS from year 2020.

---

```
let romNumbers={'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000}
```

You can filter `romNumbers` object by key:

```
const filteredByKey = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(romNumbers).filter(([key, value]) => key === 'I') )
// filteredByKey = {I: 1}
```

Or  filter `romNumbers` object by value:

```
 const filteredByValue = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(romNumbers).filter(([key, value]) => value === 5) )
 // filteredByValue = {V: 5}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Breaking an Object into `entries`, filtering by desired conditions, then create a new Object with `fromEntries`.

Comment: I used that solution to filter the object by multiple keys via `includes`. 

`Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(romNumbers).filter(([key, value]) => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].includes(key)))`

Comment: Not sure why you repeat an answer that was given more than a [year earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616104/5459839)

Comment: For anyone using multidimensional objects, change '=> value === 5' to '=> value.secondaryValue === 5'

Answer (score 31):

If you're willing to use *underscore* or *lodash*, you can use [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) (or its opposite, [`omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit)).

Examples from underscore's docs:

```js
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
// {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

Or with a callback (for *lodash*, use [pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy)):

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {
  return _.isNumber(value);
});
// {age: 50}
```

Comment: lodash is a bad solution because filtering for empty objects will also remove numbers.

Comment: I just used lodash for this and it's a great solution. Thanks @Bogdan D!

Comment: @mibbit can you be more specific? I believe it's just a matter of implementing the callback correctly

Answer (score 25):

**ES6** approach...

Imagine you have this object below:

```
const developers = {
  1: {
   id: 1,
   name: "Brendan", 
   family: "Eich"
  },
  2: {
   id: 2,
   name: "John", 
   family: "Resig"
  },  
  3: {
   id: 3,
   name: "Alireza", 
   family: "Dezfoolian"
 }
};
```

Create a function:

```
const filterObject = (obj, filter, filterValue) => 
   Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, val) => 
   (obj[val][filter] === filterValue ? acc : {
       ...acc,
       [val]: obj[val]
   }                                        
), {});
```

And call it:

```
filterObject(developers, "name", "Alireza");
```

and will **return**:

```
{
  1: {
  id: 1,
  name: "Brendan", 
  family: "Eich"
  },
  2: {
   id: 2,
   name: "John", 
   family: "Resig"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good! But why does it return just the other object (and not the one with the name/filterValue of "Alireza")?

Comment: @Pille, the OP asked for it to be like that (note the negative filter with `!predicate` in their own code).

Answer (score 10):

Given

```
object = {firstname: 'abd', lastname:'tm', age:16, school:'insat'};

keys = ['firstname', 'age'];
```

then  :

```
keys.reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: object[key] }), {});
// {firstname:'abd', age: 16}
```

```js
// Helper
function filter(object, ...keys) {
  return keys.reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: object[key] }), {});
  
};

//Example
const person = {firstname: 'abd', lastname:'tm', age:16, school:'insat'};

// Expected to pick only firstname and age keys
console.log(
  filter(person, 'firstname', 'age')
)
```

Comment: This does not use a given predicate function as is required by the question.

Answer (score 9):

As patrick already stated this is a bad idea, as it will almost certainly break any 3rd party code you could ever wish to use.

All libraries like jquery or prototype will break if you extend `Object.prototype`, the reason being that lazy iteration over objects (without `hasOwnProperty` checks) will break since the functions you add will be part of the iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Plain ES6:

```
var foo = {
    bar: "Yes"
};

const res = Object.keys(foo).filter(i => foo[i] === 'Yes')

console.log(res)
// ["bar"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I have created an `Object.filter()` which does not only filter by a function, but also accepts an array of keys to include. The optional third parameter will allow you to invert the filter.

#### Given:

```
var foo = {
    x: 1,
    y: 0,
    z: -1,
    a: 'Hello',
    b: 'World'
}
```

#### Array:

```
Object.filter(foo, ['z', 'a', 'b'], true);
```

#### Function:

```
Object.filter(foo, function (key, value) {
    return Ext.isString(value);
});
```

### Code

***Disclaimer***: I chose to use Ext JS core for brevity. Did not feel it was necessary to write type checkers for object types as it was not part of the question.

```js
// Helper function
function print(obj) {
    document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, '  ') + '<br />';
    console.log(obj);
}

Object.filter = function (obj, ignore, invert) {
    let result = {}; // Returns a filtered copy of the original list
    if (ignore === undefined) {
        return obj;   
    }
    invert = invert || false;
    let not = function(condition, yes) { return yes ? !condition : condition; };
    let isArray = Ext.isArray(ignore);
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
                !(isArray && not(!Ext.Array.contains(ignore, key), invert)) &&
                !(!isArray && not(!ignore.call(undefined, key, obj[key]), invert))) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
};

let foo = {
    x: 1,
    y: 0,
    z: -1,
    a: 'Hello',
    b: 'World'
};

print(Object.filter(foo, ['z', 'a', 'b'], true));
print(Object.filter(foo, (key, value) => Ext.isString(value)));
```

```css
#disp {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/builds/ext-core.min.js"></script>
<div id="disp"></div>
```

Comment: Please check my vanilla [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767983/3645375) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/khullah/872d5a174108823159d845cc5baba337)

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
function filterObj(keys, obj) {
  const newObj = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Or...

```
function filterObj(keys, obj) {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    var foo = {
    bar: "Yes",
    pipe: "No"
};

const ret =  Object.entries(foo).filter(([key, value])=> value === 'Yes');
```

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/filter-object

Answer (score 4):

My opinionated solution:

```
function objFilter(obj, filter, nonstrict){
  r = {}
  if (!filter) return {}
  if (typeof filter == 'string') return {[filter]: obj[filter]}
  for (p in obj) {
    if (typeof filter == 'object' &&  nonstrict && obj[p] ==  filter[p]) r[p] = obj[p]
    else if (typeof filter == 'object' && !nonstrict && obj[p] === filter[p]) r[p] = obj[p]
    else if (typeof filter == 'function'){ if (filter(obj[p],p,obj)) r[p] = obj[p]}
    else if (filter.length && filter.includes(p)) r[p] = obj[p]
  }
  return r
}
```

Test cases:

```
obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

objFilter(obj, 'a') // returns: {a: 1}
objFilter(obj, ['a','b']) // returns: {a: 1, b: 2}
objFilter(obj, {a:1}) // returns: {a: 1}
objFilter(obj, {'a':'1'}, true) // returns: {a: 1}
objFilter(obj, (v,k,o) => v%2===1) // returns: {a: 1, c: 3}
```

https://gist.github.com/bernardoadc/872d5a174108823159d845cc5baba337

Answer (score 3):

If you have [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol) properties in your object, that should be filtered too, you can **not** use: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), ... because:

> `Symbol` keys are not  [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#symbols_and_for...in_iteration) !

You could use [`Reflect.ownKeys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys) and filter keys in [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
Reflect.ownKeys(o).reduce((a, k) => allow.includes(k) && {...a, [k]: o[k]} || a, {});
```

(Open DevTools for log output - Symbols are not logged on Stackoverflow UI)

```js
const bKey = Symbol('b_k');
const o = {
    a:                 1,
    [bKey]:            'b',
    c:                 [1, 3],
    [Symbol.for('d')]: 'd'
};

const allow = ['a', bKey, Symbol.for('d')];

const z1 = Reflect.ownKeys(o).reduce((a, k) => allow.includes(k) && {...a, [k]: o[k]} || a, {});

console.log(z1);                   // {a: 1, Symbol(b_k): "b", Symbol(d): "d"}
console.log(bKey in z1)            // true
console.log(Symbol.for('d') in z1) // true
```

This is equal to this

```
const z2 = Reflect.ownKeys(o).reduce((a, k) => allow.includes(k) && Object.assign(a, {[k]: o[k]}) || a, {});
const z3 = Reflect.ownKeys(o).reduce((a, k) => allow.includes(k) && Object.defineProperty(a, k, {value: o[k]}) || a, {});

console.log(z2); // {a: 1, Symbol(b_k): "b", Symbol(d): "d"}
console.log(z3); // {a: 1, Symbol(b_k): "b", Symbol(d): "d"}
```

Wrapped in a `filter()` function, an optional `target` object could be passed

```
const filter = (o, allow, t = {}) => Reflect.ownKeys(o).reduce(
    (a, k) => allow.includes(k) && {...a, [k]: o[k]} || a, 
    t
);

console.log(filter(o, allow));           // {a: 1, Symbol(b_k): "b", Symbol(d): "d"}
console.log(filter(o, allow, {e: 'e'})); // {a: 1, e: "e", Symbol(b_k): "b", Symbol(d): "d"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this where you are filtering on the entries to find the key provided and return the value

```
   let func = function(items){
      let val
      Object.entries(this.items).map(k => {
        if(k[0]===kind){
         val = k[1]
        }
      })
      return val
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mutate the same object rather than create a new one.

The following example will delete all 0 or empty values:

```
const sev = { a: 1, b: 0, c: 3 };
const deleteKeysBy = (obj, predicate) =>
  Object.keys(obj)
    .forEach( (key) => {
      if (predicate(obj[key])) {
        delete(obj[key]);
      }
    });

deleteKeysBy(sev, val => !val);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add the way that I do it because it saves me creating extra functions, I think is cleaner and I didn't see this answer:

```
let object = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
[object].map(({a,c}) => ({a,c}))[0]; // {a:1, c:2}
```

The cool thing is that also works on arrays of objects:

```
let object2 = {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6, d: 7};
[object, object2].map(({a,b,c,d}) => ({a,c})); //[{"a":1,"c":3},{"a":4,"c":6}]
[object, object2].map(({a,d}) => ({a,d})); //[{"a":1,"d":undefined},{"a":4,"d":7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, do not screw around with prototype. Instead, simply write a function to do so. Here is my version with `lodash`:

```
import each from 'lodash/each';
import get from 'lodash/get';

const myFilteredResults = results => {
  const filteredResults = [];

  each(results, obj => {
    // filter by whatever logic you want.

    // sample example
    const someBoolean = get(obj, 'some_boolean', '');

    if (someBoolean) {
      filteredResults.push(obj);
    }
  });

  return filteredResults;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the original object, this is a simple, very boring answer that doesn't waste memory:

```
const obj = {'a': 'want this', 'b': 'want this too', 'x': 'remove this'}
const keep = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

function filterObject(obj, keep) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (!keep.has(key)) {
      delete obj[key]
    }
  })
}
```

If you're only filtering a small number of objects, and your objects don't have many keys, you might not want to bother with constructing a `Set`, in which case use `array.includes` instead of `set.has`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Lodash's `_.omit()` function, which creates a new object excluding the specified key. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
const filteredObj = _.omit(obj, 'bar');

console.log(filteredObj); // Output: { foo: 1 }
```

In this code, `_.omit(obj, 'bar')` creates a new object excluding the key `'bar'` from the `obj` object, and `filteredObj` will contain `{ foo: 1 }`.

Answer (score -2):

In these cases I use the jquery $.map, which can handle objects. As mentioned on other answers, it's not a good practice to change native prototypes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes)

Below is an example of filtering just by checking some property of your object. It returns the own object if your condition is true or returns `undefined` if not. The `undefined` property will make that record disappear from your object list;

```
$.map(yourObject, (el, index)=>{
    return el.yourProperty ? el : undefined;
});
```

Comment: `$.map` can take an object, but it returns an array, so the original property names are lost. The OP needs a filtered plain object.