# Reading results of BlueBird Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've been having trouble learning callbacks and promises coming from a synchronous programming language. I've been trying to get the result of the `.env` file, so then I can use it in my application but instead `console.log(envdata)` returns:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _progressHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _settledValue: undefined
}
```

In my console. How do I instead get the correct results from the file?

Here is my current code.

```
'use strict';

var envdata = {};
var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

module.exports = function(app, options) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            envdata = getenvdata(options.basedir + path.sep + ".env");
            console.log(envdata); //need this to be the data
            app.envdata = envdata;
            resolve(app);
    });

    function getenvdata(path){
        return fs.readFileAsync(path, 'utf8')
        .then(function(data){
            data.split("\n").forEach(function(keyvalue) {
                var array = keyvalue.split('=');
                array[1] && (data[array[0]] = array[1]);
            });
            return data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a difference between promise and an async call ^ @marvel308

Comment: @Albert No, there actually isn't.

Comment: Regardless, I'm trying to find out how to read the result of a bluebird promise, instead of the actual bluebird promise object

Comment: You need a `.then` callback, or use an `async` function with an `await` statement. Both are covered in the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the value of a promise you must attach yourself to the promise chain (i.e., you must register an event handler). This is done through `.then()` and the other Promise methods, as already noted.

I have are some remarks about your code though.

- First off, don't use `new Promise()` *unless* you are promisfying a non-promise asynchronous function, i.e. one that relies on a callback. This is not the case here, so `new Promise()` should be avoided (this is called the [Explicit Promise Construction Anipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)). `readFileAsync` already returns a promise, just keep using that one.
- Promisifying functions yourself is itself something you should avoid in favor of utility functions like Bluebird's `promisifyAll` or node's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).
- `fs` is a core module, you don't really need to require it.
- The process of reading a file, splitting it into lines and then into keys and values can be implemented as a map-reduce operation, which Bluebird actually has neat helpers for.
- Last but not least, look into [`async`/`avait`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await).

Consider this alternative take:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

module.exports = function(app, options) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(path.join(options.basedir, ".env"), 'utf8')
        .then(data => data.split("\n"))
        .map(line => line.split('='))
        .filter(keyval => keyval[1] > '')
        .reduce((obj, keyval) => { obj[keyval[0]] = keyval[1]; return obj;}, {});
    });
}
```

The last step creates a key-value object from the file entries. An alternative way of writing this in ES6 can be seen [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682482/18771).

usage

```
var readEnvAsync = require('readEnvAsync');

readEnvAsync().then(env => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Interesting regarding the chaining of utility functions, I've used it in my code.  Thanks for the extra info. I understand promises a lot better now.

Comment: They can come in handy, one of the really nice features of Bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

The `getenvdata` is returning a promise so you need to use `then` function to collect your result like this

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            getenvdata(options.basedir + path.sep + ".env").then(function(envdata){
            console.log(envdata); //need this to be the data
            app.envdata = envdata;
            resolve(app);
         })
    });
```

Comment: @Albert This is exactly what the duplicate question was about.

Comment: @str my bad, I just thought promises aren't like callbacks