# How to modified Array of object in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is processed data(**INPUT**).

```
[['dObjectData.question':{ '$regex': '^(abc)', '$options': 'i'}],
 ['dObjectData.answer': { '$regex': '.*(pqr).*','$options': 'i' }]]
```

I want to make(modified this process data) in this format(**OUTPUT**).

```
[{'dObjectData.question':{'$regex':'^(abc)','$options':'i'},
   'dObjectData.answer':{'$regex': '.*(pqr).*', '$options':'i'}]
```

Comment: Your input seems invalid javascript. Should the `:` between key and value be a `,`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an object from an Array of key-value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059995/how-to-create-an-object-from-an-array-of-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that:

```
x = [
    [
        'dObjectData.question', {
            '$regex': '^(abc)',
            '$options': 'i'
        }
    ],
    [
        'dObjectData.answer', {
            '$regex': '.*(pqr).*',
            '$options': 'i'
        }
    ]
]
o = x.reduce(function (p, c) {
    p[c[0]] = c[1];
    return p;
}, [])
console.log(o)
```

The output like that：

```
[ 'dObjectData.question': { '$regex': '^(abc)', '$options': 'i' },
  'dObjectData.answer': { '$regex': '.*(pqr).*', '$options': 'i' } ]
```

Comment: Your answer is *almost* identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656472/3297291) from the question linked in the comments, but includes a mistake. Your output is invalid, and the seed for the `reduce` has to be an object. You might want to fix it to `o = [ x.reduce( ... , { } ) ];`