# Using regex when searching in the object key values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume I have an object as;

```
test = Object
    3232@alex= Object
    5656@alex= Object
    8383@felix= Object
    98232@tom= Object
```

I want to get the objects in test where the key value contains alex, I mean the first two objects.

```
3232@alex= Object
5656@alex= Object
```

Normally I reach them as `test["3232@alex"]` or `test."3232@alex".`
Now can I write a regex expression to get the objects where key contains "`alex`" for example.I know I can loop through the object as;

```
var arr = [];
for(var key in test){
    if(key.contains("alex")){
       arr.push(test[key]);
    }
}
```

Is it the only way to do it? I'm actually looking for a solution which avoids loop.

Comment: think loop is most fastest way to do it. Also, `test."3232@alex"` will not work.

Comment: also, you can do this one Object.keys(test).forEach(function(v){if(v.contains)...}), but it will not work in IE9.

Comment: There are other ways of doing this, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects), but fundamentally you are going to have a loop over the object keys somewhere, it can't be avoided.

Comment: @degr Nor will it work in Netscape Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm actually looking for a solution which avoids loop.

You have a bunch of things (object keys) that you want to look through to find matching ones. "Looking through" is by definition a loop. You can't avoid a loop. The only question is whether you will write the loop yourself (`for (...)`), or use some library utility or function that loops for you behind the scenes. Which to use is to some extent a matter of preference. It would not be surprising if the loop you wrote yourself ran faster, in case you care.

One example is `filter`:

```
Object.keys(test)
  .filter(key => /alex/.test(key)
  .forEach(key => console.log(key, test[key]));
```