# How to loop over a nested JavaScript object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am new to Javascript and jQuery. I am trying to create something like this (object) below and read the keys and retrieve the values.

```
var members = {unit:1,name: ["AA", "AB"],userid:["0001","0002"],
              {unit:2,name: ["BA", "BB"],userid:["0011","0012"]};
```

if `'Unit' == 1` then display name array.

Basically I want loop through the object and retrieve the value.

Comment: The object that you have given is invalid. It looks like, It has to be wrapped inside an array.

Comment: you have multiple properties with same name in a single object (?) you have one missing closing `}`.. do you mean an array of objects? [edit] your question please.

Comment: structure was not proper. your object should be, [{},{}] but currently its like {{}. rewrite it

Comment: This question has been heavily downvoted, and it is worth taking a moment to understand why. Your title ("I want a solution in JavaScript please") seems to be a demand for free work rather than a statement of the problem. I have trimmed similar fluff material from the body as well. It also isn't clear, and there is no attempt at a solution. Did you try something before asking? That is really important here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Answer (score 4):

I think you member should be like this

```
var members = [{unit:1,name: ["AA", "AB"],userid:["0001","0002"]},
                  {unit:2,name: ["BA", "BB"],userid:["0011","0012"]}];
```

```js
var members = [{unit:1,name: ["AA", "AB"],userid:["0001","0002"]},
              {unit:2,name: ["BA", "BB"],userid:["0011","0012"]}];
              
        members.forEach(function(v,i){
        
            if(v.unit==1)
            {
            
              console.log(v.name);
            }
        
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is want you wanted, an object within an object. Where 'unit' is the key for retrieving the objects within the object.

```js
var members = {
    1: {
        name: ["test","test"],
        userid: ["0001","0002"]},
    2: {
        name: ["test2", "test2"],
        userid: ["0011", "0012"]}
};

console.log(members[1]);
```

Comment: Hi Hedylogos. I wanted something similar to your reply and I found the answer. Thank you very much

Comment: var members = {
  member:[ {"unit" : 4,"unit_name":"Ma","names":['-Select your name-','Mattias','Johan','Cecilia','Tuomas','Charika'],"codes":['0','199930','440720','237720','111111','111112']},
  {"unit" : 5,"unit_name":"CM","names":['-Select your name-','Lena','Mariat','Annika'], "codes":['0','346710','297380']}
  ]}