# Use array.some to return only matching sub-objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a list of requested colours that I am passing to a function:

```
const requestedColours = ['blue','green'];
```

I pass this into a function which contains an object with details of various colours:

```
colorOptions(requestedColours) {
    const options = {
        blue: {
            icon: 'sea.jpg',
            title: 'Sea Blue',
        },
        green: {
            icon: 'leaf.jpg',
            title: 'Leafy green',
        },
        pink: {
            icon: 'flower.jpg',
            title: 'Rose Pink',
        }
     }

    return options.some(requestedColours);
}
```

The following line I'm aware is incorrect:

`return options.some(requestedColours);`

However I also tried, for example:

`return options.some('blue');`

And this does not return the sub-object for `blue`, **how do I correctly use `array.some`?**

Comment: you are calling a function that's defined on `Array.prototype` on an object.

Comment: But what do you want to get? Boolean or modified options object?

Comment: @Kinduser modified options object with only the two requested colours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Answer (score 1):

`Array#reduce` over `requestedColours` array.

**Note**: A wise idea would be also moving the `options` object outside the function.

```js
const requestedColours = ['blue', 'green'];
const options = {
  blue: {
    icon: 'sea.jpg',
    title: 'Sea Blue',
  },
  green: {
    icon: 'leaf.jpg',
    title: 'Leafy green',
  },
  pink: {
    icon: 'flower.jpg',
    title: 'Rose Pink',
  }
};

const colorOptions = (obj, arr) => {
  return requestedColours.reduce((s, a) => {
    if (a in options) {
      s[a] = obj[a];
    }
    return s;
  }, {});
};

console.log(colorOptions(options, requestedColours));
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient. Instead of looking at all keys and checking for each whether it is in the array, one could `reduce` over the selection array right away.

Comment: @Bergi You're a genius.

Answer (score 0):

The `some` function takes a function and uses it to test each element of the array. It returns true if the function returns true for any element of the array. For example, if I wanted to check if an array contained at least one element that was greater than 5, I might try:

```
[1, 2, 5, 7].some(function(elem) { return elem > 5; })
```

I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve in the above function, but I don't think the `some` function meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`some` is a method in the `array` prototype that takes a *function* and returns either `true` or `false`. It runs the function with the items in the array until it returns a truthy value. If none appears, it returns `false`.

### If your goal is to see if the `requestedColors` are in `options`:

- define a function that tells you if a key is in an object
- pass this function to `some`

i.e.:

```js
var requestedColours=["blue","green"];
var options={blue:{icon:"sea.jpg",title:"Sea Blue"},green:{icon:"leaf.jpg",title:"Leafy green"},pink:{icon:"flower.jpg",title:"Rose Pink"}};

var objectHasKey = obj => key => key in obj;

console.log(
  requestedColours.some(objectHasKey(options))
);
```

### If your goal is to create an array of requested options:

- define a function that retrieves a property's value from an object
- use `map` to map from key to option
- filter out options that don't exist

```js
var requestedColours=["red", "blue","green"];
var options={blue:{icon:"sea.jpg",title:"Sea Blue"},green:{icon:"leaf.jpg",title:"Leafy green"},pink:{icon:"flower.jpg",title:"Rose Pink"}};

var getKey = obj => key => obj[key];

console.log(
  requestedColours
    .map(getKey(options))
    .filter(opt => opt)
);
```

### If your goal is to create a new options object with only the requested colours:

You can do this in one loop, using one `reduce` method:

- Reduce `requestedColours`
- Retrieve the options object from `options` using the key
- Merge it with the accumulator you pass along in the reducer

```js
const requestedColours = ['blue', 'green'];
const options = {
  blue: {
    icon: 'sea.jpg',
    title: 'Sea Blue',
  },
  green: {
    icon: 'leaf.jpg',
    title: 'Leafy green',
  },
  pink: {
    icon: 'flower.jpg',
    title: 'Rose Pink',
  }
}

const pickedColors = requestedColours.reduce(
  (picked, key) => Object.assign(picked, { [key]: options[key] }),
  {}
);

console.log(pickedColors);
```