# How to push not empty key value object into an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an object with some key:value pairs. I would like to push the object into an array but without the empty object value.

my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/howw1fj7/

```js
var myData = [];

var myObj = {
  product: "phone",
  quantity: 100,
  color: "red",
  secondColor: '',
  imei: "43904325"
};
myData.push(myObj); //push only not empty key:values 
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

i have tried something like this but this is not correct:

```
$.each(myObj, function(key, value) {
    if(value.length !=0) {
    var myNewObj = {key:value};
    myData.push(myNewObj);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your definition of *empty*? A `''` string? Zero? `null`? `undefined`? `NaN`?

Comment: If you want to name a property dynamically in an object literal, the syntax should be: `{ [key]: value }`. Of course the interpreter should support es6.

Comment: in this case empty definition is A `' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for in` loop to iterate through the `myObj` and check for the empty value. Then you can push the new object created into the array.

```js
var myData = [];

var myObj = { product: "phone", quantity: 100, color: "red", secondColor:'', imei: "43904325" };

var obj = {};

for(var key in myObj) {
  if(myObj[key] !== '') {
    obj[key] = myObj[key];
  }
}

myData.push(obj);

$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(myData,null,4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: this is the solution i was looking for. in the if statement i can also check if there is something undefined or null.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a utility method `Object.filter` as described [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616104/5459839).

Then you get this:

```js
Object.from = arr => Object.assign(...arr.map( ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}) ));
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => Object.from(Object.entries(obj).filter(predicate));

var myData = [];
var myObj = { product: "phone", quantity: 100, color: "red", secondColor:'', imei: "43904325" };

myData.push(Object.filter(myObj, ([k, v]) => v !== ''));
console.log(myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` will not have a `.length` as it is not an array but a property in the array that you are looping over. You would need to check for `null`,`''`,`undefined`

Comment: disagree , if the `value` is a string then it will have the `length` property

Comment: true. but then you are only looking at strings