# How to filter records based on the status value in JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, jsobject

I have JS object that looks like this:

```
{
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(508) 233-8908",
    "status": 0
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(509) 874-9411",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

I would like to filter through the object and for example pull only record which status is '1'. One solution for that is to use array filter like this:

```
var filterJSON = Object.values(obj).filter(function (entry) {
                switch(frmFilter){
                    case '1':
                        return entry.status === 1;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        return entry.status === 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return entry;
                }
            });
```

problem is code above will convert data into array like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(508) 233-8908",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(509) 874-9411",
    "status": 1
  }
]
```

As you can see data set is an array, I want to keep my data in object same as one in the first example before filter was applied. Is there a way to filter through the object and achieve the same output as one with filtering through array?

Comment: Will `for...in` loop help?

Comment: @samuellawrentz Maybe, I'm not sure what is your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert the filtered array back into an object:

```js
var obj = {
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(508) 233-8908",
    "status": 0
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(509) 874-9411",
    "status": 1
  }
}

var frmFilter = "1";

var filterJSON = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    let entry = obj[key];
    switch(frmFilter){
        case '1':
            return entry.status === 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            return entry.status === 0;
            break;
        default:
            return entry;
    }
}).reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );

console.log(filterJSON);
```

Had some help from this answer: [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? I'm not familiar with `reduce()` method.

Comment: @espresso_coffee See the links I posted. The javascript documentation will be better than any explanation I can give, and will provide many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = {
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(508) 233-8908",
    "status": 0
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(509) 874-9411",
    "status": 1
  }
};

const filtered = Object.values(data).filter(e => e.status == 1);
const output = {};
filtered.forEach(e => output[e.id] = e);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can I use `switch` inside filter like I do in my example?

Comment: @espresso_coffee you can, but filter needs to return a `bool`, check out the revised code it will filter the results and rebuild an object.

Comment: Doesn't this assume the 'id' field in the nested objects is the same as the key in the parent?

Comment: @AbidHasan ya it does

Comment: If you're going to be mapping the items into output, and not returning anything from map, you should simply just use `.forEach()` on `filtered`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the filter Array function, it returns a simple array, not an object like the original (`obj`)

You can do a simple for-each copying and modifying object properties in another object:

```
var filterJSON = {};
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){

        switch(frmFilter){
                case '1':
                    if (filterJSON[key].status == 1){
                       filterJSON[key] = obj[key];
                    } 
                    break;
                case '2':
                    if (filterJSON[key].status == 0){
                       filterJSON[key] = obj[key];
                    }
                    break;
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you loop through an object, always check if the object [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). Additionally, this code doesn't work at all. `filterJSON[key].status === 1` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
const filter = (data, predicate) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (predicate(data[current])) {
      acc[current] = data[current];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

// result contains only items with status of 1
const result = filter(data, (item) => item.status === 1);

// result2 contains only items with last name of length > 4
const result2 = filter(data, (item) => item.last.length > 4);
```

The predicate is called on each item and if it returns true the item is included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I was telling the `for...in` loop in JS that is used to iterate over the properties of an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```js
var obj = {
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(508) 233-8908",
    "status": 0
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(509) 874-9411",
    "status": 1
  }
}
var filteredObj = {};
for (var props in obj){
  if(obj[props].status===1)
  filteredObj[props] = obj[props] ; 
  }
  
  console.log(filteredObj)
```

You are iterating over properties of `obj` and checking for status. If `status` equals 1 we are assigning that property to the `filteredObj` Object.