# Filter json objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My object is as below

```
    "permission": {
      "delete": {
        "253": false,
        "255": true
      }
    }
```

How would I filter to find if 255 is true

Comment: When you say filter, what exactly do you mean? Are you just trying to access that property? If so, couldn't you just use something like `parent.permission.delete["255"]`? (Assuming you parse your JSON as a JS object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Comment: the word "filter" is typically used when referring to selecting a subset of items from a set whose attributes match a set of criteria. are you asking to find all properties (subset) of the "delete" object properties (set) that match the criteria of "having the boolean value 'true'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const test = {
  "permission": {
      "delete": {
        "253": false,
        "255": true
      }
    }
}

const hasDelete255 = test.permission.delete["255"];
console.log(hasDelete255)
```