# How do I filter a list using parmeters within a nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a `list` that I want to filter using parameters from `advancedSearchFilters` which has nested objects. I want to return a list that matches all parameters if any.

```
const list = [
  {
    additionalPrices: 0,
    clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
    companyName: 'Test Company',
    completeDate: 'Invalid date',
    createdAt: '2019-09-08 16:41:43',
    createdBy: 'test@test.com',
    deliveryDate: '2019-09-14 16:39:25',
    driver: 'Robert Kaszkiewicz',
    dropOff: 'Avenida Callao 1234, Buenos Aires, Argentina',
    height: 23,
    isPreparingTrailer: true,
    isSmsSent: true,
    isTrailerReady: true,
    key: '2104a7bd-5e78-49ce-a1f6-0699ac98f264',
    notes: '',
    pickUp: 'Poprad, Slovakia',
    price: 1400,
    quantity: 2,
    trailer: 'einzeln',
    vehicle: 'Sattel',
    vehicleClass: 'Mega',
    vehicleId: '12313',
    vehicleReadyDate: '2019-09-27 16:41:22',
    weight: 123
  },
  {
    clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
    companyName: 'Test Company',
    createdAt: '2019-09-26 18:32:18',
    createdBy: 'test@test.com',
    deliveryDate: '2019-09-20 18:31:45',
    driver: 'Michal Kucharski',
    dropOff: 'Logroño, Spain',
    height: 0,
    isPreparingTrailer: false,
    isSmsSent: false,
    isTrailerReady: false,
    key: '388113f5-3927-4fe3-80d5-f2fcf1c7cedd',
    notes: '',
    orderId: '',
    pickUp: '16671 Butano Place, Fontana, CA, USA',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    trailer: '2er Pack',
    vehicle: 'Sattel',
    vehicleClass: 'Standard',
    vehicleId: 'efgefg',
    vehicleReadyDate: '2019-09-27 18:32:08',
    weight: 0
  },
  {
    clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
    companyName: 'Test Company',
    createdAt: '2019-10-07 14:59:28',
    createdBy: 'test@test.com',
    deliveryDate: '2019-10-09 14:54:44',
    driver: 'Pawel Marczyk',
    dropOff: 'München, Germany',
    height: 1150,
    isPreparingTrailer: false,
    isSmsSent: false,
    isTrailerReady: false,
    key: '795e7531-8655-4e38-a576-e13483922607',
    notes: 'alle fertig, vorher anrufen',
    orderId: '',
    pickUp: 'Soest, Germany',
    price: 5000,
    quantity: 10,
    trailer: '3er Pack',
    vehicle: 'Sattel',
    vehicleClass: 'Standard',
    vehicleId: '1121+23+24',
    vehicleReadyDate: '2019-10-07 14:55:19',
    weight: 20000
  },
];
```

```js
const advancedSearchFilters = {
      companyName: {
        modifier: 'equals',
        value: 'Test Company'
      },
      price: {
        modifier: 'greaterThan',
        value: '54'
      },
      driver: {
        modifier: 'equals',
        value: 'Robert'
      }
    };

const handleFilterModifier = (value, compareValue, modifier) => {
    if (modifier === 'lessThan') {
        return value > compareValue;
    }

    if (modifier === 'equals') {
        return value === compareValue;
    }

    if (modifier === 'greaterThan') {
        return value < compareValue;
    }

    return null;
};

const resultList = list.filter(
                item => Object.entries(advancedSearchFilters).every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => {
                    const compareValue = item[filterKey].value;
                    const value = keys[filterKey];
                    list = handleFilterModifier(
                        parseFloat(value),
                        compareValue,
                        filterVal
                    );
                    return list;
                })
            );
```

The `resultList` function above returns an error.

I guess the problem arises from trying to get the query parameters from within `advancedSearchFilters`. This code will help me accomplish an advanced search feature request.

Comment: The `list` that you defined is an Object, so it doesn't have a .filter. The filter functionality only exists on Array.prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter . However, if you want that kind of functionality, there's already an answer for it here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects .

Comment: My bad.. I posted the worng dataset. It is actually an array

Answer (score 1):

As user3773048 says in the comment, Object doesn't have a `filter` method. Array, however, does.

Instead of `list.filter(item => ...)`, you can pull your inner function out, maybe call it `predicate` like so:

```js
const predicate = item => ...
```

Then use it like so:

```js
const resultList = Object.entries(list).reduce(
  (filteredList, [key, item]) => {
    if (predicate(item)) {
      filteredList[key] = item;
    }
    return filteredList;
  },
  {}
);
```

The `Object.entries()` method gives you the key/value pairs of the object as an array, and `reduce()` lets you condense the list back into key/value pairs in an object.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "you can pull your inner function out, maybe call it `predicate` like so". Could you please expatiate a bit more?

Comment: The lines you have from "item => Object.entries"... to the closing brace and parens after "return list" is what I'm referring to. Since it's a function, you can define it as its own variable. That way, you can easily call it inside an "if" statement instead if trying to inline the whole thing in there. I chose the name "predicate" because that's a common term for a check on an object that returns a boolean, but whatever name.makes.most sense for you.