# UseEffect execution somehow depending on function call within itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a peculiar problem when using the useEffect-hook in React Native. I have a functional component, which has one useEffect-hook that fetches data for pinpoints and another that then rearranges the pinpoints (`filteredPinpoints`) into a useable format. `filteredPinpoints` is updated three times, but the first two times, the object is empty.

Now the weird behaviour: if I comment out `dispatch(organiseRoutes(...))` in the second useEffect, this useEffect is called three times, but if I want to execute the dispatch function, the useEffect is only called twice. Since I return early if `filteredPinpoints` is empty, the code never reaches the dispatch.

**EDIT**: Also, when I implement `dispatch(organiseRoutes(...))`, the app freezes, only showing the (spinning) ActivityIndicator, but leaving me unable to navigate to the previous screen again.

What do I have to change, so that the useEffect is run every single time `filteredPinpoints` is updated?

```
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getRouteData, organiseRoutes } from '../utils';

export default function RoutePreviewScreen() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const currentRouteID = useSelector(state => state.currentRouteID);
    const filteredPinpoints = useSelector(state =>
        // Uses ObjectFilter from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects/37616104
        ObjectFilter(state.allPinpoints, pinpoint => pinpoint.Route_ID == state.currentRouteID)
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // This updates state.allPinpoints.
    useEffect(() => {
        (async function myFirstAsyncFunction() {
            await dispatch(getRouteData(currentRouteID));
        })();
    }, [currentRouteID]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(filteredPinpoints).length === 0) {
            return
        }

        console.log("Could EXECUTE now!!")

        // If the following line is commented out, the useEffect executes a third time.
        // However, only in the third run, filteredPinpoints is not a empty object.
        // If it is not commented out, it simply refuses to execute a third time.
        dispatch(organiseRoutes(filteredPinpoints));

        setLoadingData(false)
    }, [filteredPinpoints]);

    if (loadingData) { return (<View><ActivityIndicator/></View>)}

    return(<ComponentUsingOrganisedRoutes/>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fixed it. Pretty stupid mistake. Basically, organiseRoutes() affects filteredPinpoints, so useEffect is caught in an infinite loop. I guess in these scenarios, console.log() is not called because it's being blocked.

I introduced a new state-hook `organisedData` aside to `loadingData`, to give the second useEffect another value to check for before it executes the dispatch. Once `organisedData` is `true`, it's going to stop executing and thereby stop triggering itself now.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getRouteData, organiseRoutes } from '../utils';

export default function RoutePreviewScreen() {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const currentRouteID = useSelector(state => state.currentRouteID);
    const filteredPinpoints = useSelector(state =>
        ObjectFilter(state.allPinpoints, pinpoint => pinpoint.Route_ID == state.currentRouteID)
    );

    // New:
    const [organisedData, setOrganisedData] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function myFirstAsyncFunction() {

            // New:
            setLoadingData(true)

            await dispatch(getRouteData(currentRouteID));

            // New:
            setOrganisedData(false)
        })();
    }, [currentRouteID]);

    useEffect(() => {

        // New:
        if (!loadingData || organisedData) {
            return
        }

        if (Object.keys(filteredPinpoints).length === 0) {
            return
        }

        // New:
        setOrganisedData(true)

        dispatch(organiseRoutes(filteredPinpoints));

        // New:
        setLoadingData(false)

    // Adjusted:
    }, [organisedData, loadingData, filteredPinpoints]);

    if (loadingData) { return (<View><ActivityIndicator/></View>)}

    return(<ComponentUsingOrganisedRoutes/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `filteredPinpoints` is an object. useEffect does not do a deep equality check on object, for that you'll have to deal with it differently.

You can use a dependency like: `[JSON.stringify(filteredPinpoints)]`, which would do a better check and won't be as slow as a deep equality check.

ref: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1104414272753487872

Comment: Just checked, but the behavior is the same. `console.log("Could EXECUTE now!!")` is only called if `dispatch(organiseRoutes(filteredPinpoints))` is commented out.

Comment: Maybe try adding `Object.keys(filteredPinpoints).length` as the useEffect dependency?