# Javascript filter arrays within an object

Tags: javascript, object, filter, reduce

Let's say I have an object with the structure

```js
data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}
```

I want to extract elements where `key2 == "abc"`.

Expected output:

```js
data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}
```

I've tried to follow similar [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects) but failed to implement what I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to extract all the key / value pairs of `data` as an array, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each pair and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on each value to extract the ones you want.

You can then join it back up using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}

const findKey = 'key2'
const findValue = 'abc'

const newData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([ key, val ]) =>
  [ key, val.filter(({ values }) => values?.[findKey] === findValue) ]))
  
console.log(newData)
```

---

In case you haven't seen [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) yet, this...

```js
values?.[findKey] === findValue
```

is equivalent to

```js
!!values && values[findKey] === findValue
```

Comment: My brain hurts trying to follow all the destructuring going on there.

Comment: While this works there is so much destructuring here that you might loose the flow

Comment: @ManosKounelakis there are only two destructures here, one array (`[ key, val ]`) and one object (`{ value }`). Not sure what you consider too much?

Comment: do you actually need the optional chaining? i thought if you try to access a property at the first layer that is not there it returns undefined?

Comment: @Ifaruki it's there in case any of the array entries doesn't have a `values` property. If they did, `values` would be `undefined` and `values[findKey]` would throw an error

Comment: At first glance I saw the return value of the arrow callback inside map and thought it was a destructure.

Comment: i know i was just thinking about that because they OP didnt say that it could happen that there is no `values` available.

Answer (score 4):

Simple [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop that iterates over keys and [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the arrays and reassigns properties directly.
Mutates data directly.

Uses [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) key2 to filter on it.

```js
const data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}

for(const k of Object.keys(data))
  data[k] = data[k].filter(({values: {key2}})=>key2==='abc')
  
console.log(data)
```

Added check of .length to prune keys with empty arrays,
and set default value for key2 so values property is optional:

```js
const data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}

for(const k of Object.keys(data))
  (data[k] = data[k].filter(({values:{key2}={}})=>key2==='abc'))
    .length || delete data[k]
  
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the properties of the object to the ones that pass a filter

```js
const data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
};

const results = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).reduce((results, key) => {
  const filtered = data[key].filter(item => item.values.key2 === 'abc');
  if (filtered && filtered.length) {
    results[key] = filtered;
  }
  return results;
}, {});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Might need to clarify with OP if they want empty results omitted but that's a nice addition

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
    a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 4, key2: "cde"}}],
    b : [{values: {key1: 3, key2: "ffe"}}, {values: {key1: 11, key2: "gga"}}, {values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
}

var resp = {}
for (var key in data){
    var local = [];
    data[key].forEach(element => {
        if(element['values']['key2'] == 'abc'){
            local.push(element);
        }
    })
    resp[key] = local;
}
console.log(resp);
```

Response

```
a : [{values: {key1: 5, key2: "abc"}}, {values: {key1: 3, key2: "abc"}}],
b : [{values: {key1: 7, key2: "abc"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to iterate over your objects attributes I suggest you to extract them with `Object.keys(object)` which you can find here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys

I suggest you to iterate like this:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(attribute => {
        data[attribute] = data[attribute].filter(value => value.values.key2 === 'abc');
})
```

Good luck.