# Get specified object (key and value) based on provided value

Tags: javascript, object

lets say I have object like this:

```
{
1: [1,2,3],
2: [4,6,7],
3: [5, 8,9,10]
etc..
}
```

Now i want to get value and a key by value. So my input would be: 5 and I need to get key and value of a object that contains that 5, so it is `3:[5,8,9,10]` in the example above. The key is important just like value of a object. Is there a method for that in JS? Something like Includes on arrays or I need to loop throu it? What if object has like 10k keys?

Comment: You can access it like this: `obj['5']`.

Comment: I did a mistake and I fixed that already. The thing is I don't know they key. Only value is known.

Comment: You can look through object properties using `for(var i in obj)`. So `i` is the property name, and the value (an array in your case is `obj[i]`. So loop through and check if it contains your value.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072145/1880380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if object has like 10k keys?

You will have to iterate over all keys/properties, there is no way around this. `Array#includes` does that too, just internally.

A simple solution would be combining [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const result = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].includes(value));
```

Comment: What if I need key and a value?

Comment: Just access `obj[result]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries(). This code will return also more objects that contain the search value.

```js
const obj = {
  1: [1, 2, 3],
  2: [4, 6, 7],
  3: [5, 8, 9, 10],
  4: [5, 11, 19, 110]

}


const res = {}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  value.includes(5) ? res[key] = value : null;
}

console.log(res);
```