# Delete from object while adhering to Eslint no-param-reassign

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
Object.keys(updateValues).forEach(field => {
   allowedFields.indexOf(field) === -1 && delete updateValues[field];
});
```

In the above code I am iterating over `updateValues` and deleting indexes that no exist in allowedFields, however after enabling Eslint the `delete updateValues[field];` is failing the **no-param-reassign** rule.

I was thinking of using a method which destructures the [field] and returns the remaining. Can anyone provide an example of this or offer and direction?

Comment: "*I was thinking of using a method which destructures the [field] and returns the remaining.*" not a good approach IMO. You don't need to really loop and create many objects each with one less key. Just extract all keys -> remove the unneeded ones -> get an object with the rest of the keys.

Comment: I did think it was overthinking the problem, would you provide an example of your solution? I cannot find a way of removing that does not end up with Eslint complaining

Comment: See [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38750705) in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081419/) does exactly the same operation where you whitelist some keys and create an object from them. Multiple other solutions there including blacklisting or direct re-mapping of an object to only the expected keys. See also [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5072136)

Comment: ah yes, I understand. Thanks pal